# ReactQuill - How to style placeholder attribute?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-quill

I want to style the text assigned to the placeholder attribute and make its font size larger. How do I do this with ReactQuill?

```
          <ReactQuill placeholder= "some fun text" onChange = {onContentChange} value={contentValue} theme="snow" style={{

            height:"300px",
            padding:"20px",
            lineHeight:"0px",

          }}/>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can edit editor's styles using custom CSS. Add this to your `index.css` file or if you are using any CSS framework like `styled-components`, write this CSS there.

```
.quill > .ql-container > .ql-editor.ql-blank::before{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
}
```